# Using logical operators(OR/AND,...) in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, expression

I'm a newbie to programming,
I need to validate a couple of expressions in an if condition and when both of them returns true then only need to do some work.

I know i can do that by **using logical operators**,But i don't have clear idea about how the logical operators works.

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Thanks in-advance.

Comment: Are you asking how an if statement works?

Comment: Yes,I've updated my question and added some detailed information about my need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use of logical operators is best , multiple conditions.

for example

int firstValue=10;
    int sencondValue=16;

```
// OR operator , retursn TRUE is any of given condtion is true.
if (firstValue==10 || sencondValue==13 || firstValue>=5) {
    NSLog(@"True");
}
else
{

NSLog(@"False");


}
//above are 3 condtions in one statement , if any condition is true , result is true

// AND operator , retursn TRUE is all of given condtion are true  and flase if any on the given conditions are false.

if (firstValue==10 && sencondValue==13 && firstValue>=5) {
    NSLog(@"True");
}
else
{

    NSLog(@"False");


}
```

Answer (score 4):

As in many programming languages, there are logical operators available.

It seems like you are looking for the `AND` operator:

```
if (conditionA && conditionB) {
  // conditional code
}
```

See [Wikipedia: Logical operators in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Logical_operators) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Use the short-circuit logical and operator...

**Example 1.**

```
if (1 == 1 && 2 == 2) {
    // statements that will always execute
}
```

**Example 2**

```
boolean firstCondition = YES;
boolean secondCondition = NO;
boolean thirdCondition = YES;

if (firstCondition && secondCondition && thirdCondition) {
    // As secondCondition is false this will never execute (and thirdCondition will never be evaluated)
}
```

Using the logical and operator the statements within the curly braces will only execute if the first and second conditions evaluate to true.  Also, if the first condition is false, the second condition will not even be evaluated, hence the name short-circuit.